# Meadows with usual real division

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

A "meadow" is a commutative ring with a multiplicative identity element and a total multiplicative inverse operation satisfying the two equations $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$ and $x \times (x \times x^{-1}) = x$.

Is there a meadow in which the inverses for all reals (except zero) are the usual inverses of the field of real numbers?

References would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. Define $0^{-1}:=0$ on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the abstract of [the paper which apparently introduced meadows](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0823):

> We study a new axiomatic concept for number systems with division that uses only equations: a meadow is a commutative ring with a total inverse operator satisfying two equations which imply that the inverse of zero is zero. All fields and products of fields can be viewed as meadows.

In other words, since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field you just need to extend it with $0^{-1} = 0$.